# Group BY inside a subquery

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to select a count inside a subquery that is grouped by userid, unfortunatlly the userid has to be in the select part, and after doing so, the subquery returnes more then one value.

I Have two tables: Users that contains the column UserID and more columns, Messages that contains the column UserID (I am joining the two tables based on this column), MessageRead is a the field i want to count per user.

my query is this:

```
SELECT Users.UserID,  (SELECT COUNT(MessageRead) 
                       FROM Messages  
                       group by Messages.UserID) as d
from Messages 
right JOIN Users ON Users.UserID=Messages.UserID  group by Users.UserID;
```

thanks!

Comment: seems to me that all you need in the sub query is ...FROM MESSAGES WHERE Users.UserID = Messages.UserID  and you can then also remove the group by Messages.UserID as it will have no purpose if you are only selecting for one user

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what type of field MessageRead is. I'm guessing it's a boolean and you want to get a count of the messages that were read?

This query will get a count of all messages for a user.

`SELECT u.UserID,  COUNT(m.MessageID)
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Messages m on m.UserID = u.UserID 
GROUP BY u.UserID`

If you want only the messages that are read, try adding a WHERE clause.

`SELECT u.UserID,  COUNT(m.MessageID)
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Messages m on m.UserID = u.UserID 
WHERE m.MessageRead = 1
GROUP BY u.UserID`

The LEFT JOIN in this query will return users with 0 messages. If you want to exclude those then change it to an INNER JOIN.